# New Project - Angular 1.4 or 2.0

Tags: angularjs

This is duplicate of 
[New Project - Angular 1.4 or 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297912/new-project-angular-1-4-or-2-0) . However thats been asked 6 months back although Angular 2.0 is out now.

We are also about to start the new project with AngularJs with responsive web design to have it compatible with mobile browsers.

Which version ( 2.0 vs 1.4 ) would be recommended considering 2.0 is quite new and things may change or may not. Although I am quite keen to use 2.0 given its new features.

Your expert inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: angular 2.0 is still not released officially. The library is still in beta version, and might take another few months for official release. However, angular 1.4 is pretty much stable in comparison to 2.

Comment: See [angular 1 vs angular 2 for new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229956/angular-1-vs-angular-2-for-new-project/44328165#44328165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A source for some indicators would be https://splintercode.github.io/is-angular-2-ready/ :)

So no.

On the other hand I've heard from companies clearly working with angular 2 already. Rather smaller ones.

I would compare my project timelines with the one from angular - and consider some delays as well. If your project runs more than 6 months: maybe. Depends on what features you implement and when you do that. UI related features: the later the better.
If that looks suiteable: why not.

But consider issues with the beta software. Some issues might not be easy to identify. For ex. I tried working with the new router and ran into issues with the components and controllers. If I needed that feature (a working routing) tomorrow then angular 2 would not be the best choice.

Beside angular 2 being released, some libraries and tools may need to adopt as well, which will require some time too.

And you can not realistically plan based on announcements. Sometimes features one waits for are just moved into the next release.

So it depends on how much space is for moving work around or delay some tasks. And of course how well your developers are trained to track down arising issues and identify the cause.

If you have a release date already I would not take the risk (speaking today 28th oct 2015). I would rather learn something about the business and then migrate (do a planned migration) once I understood more.

You may ask again tomorrow ;-D

Comment: thanks for your reply, it made clear sense.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.5 is close to release (in Beta now). It will be production ready and have some great new features, like the "component" object.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/

Start with Angular 1.5, write in TypeScript, follow all the latest best practices and your code will be close to being ready for Angular 2 upgrade.